# List current user's playlists and tracks on spotify

Tags: javascript, spotify, playlist

I'm trying to list all the playlists (and their tracks) of **the current user** on a Spotify integrated app using the API as explains in https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial/tree/1.0 .

Is there any way to do this? Or is not supported by now?

Using the 1.X API I did this:

```
var returnedLibrary;
require(['$api/library#Library'], function(Library) {
  returnedLibrary = Library.forCurrentUser();
});
```

(From: https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/library_.html)

I suppose that my object `returnedLibrary` has all the playlists for the current user, isn't it? My problem is that I don't know what to do with this returned object and how to iterate through it.

Anyone knows how to access this information?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in the user's playlists, you can do it like this:

```
var returnedLibrary;
require(['$api/library#Library'], function(Library) {
  returnedLibrary = Library.forCurrentUser();
  returnedLibrary.playlists.snapshot().done(function(snapshot) {
    for (var i = 0, l = snapshot.length; i < l; i++) {
      var playlist = snapshot.get(i);
      // do something with playlist
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have achieved my purpose:

```
var returnedLibrary;
require(['$api/library#Library'], function(Library) {
  returnedLibrary = Library.forCurrentUser();
  returnedLibrary.playlists.snapshot().done(function(snapshot) {
    for (var i = 0, l = snapshot.length; i < l; i++) {
      var playlist = snapshot.get(i);
      aplay._collections();
      aplay.tracks.snapshot().done(function(s){
      selectedPlaylist = s;
      for(k=0;k<s.length;k++){
              s.get(k).name; //Will be the name of that song
      }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Nevertheless, I don't know why I have to call `aplay._collections();` (it seems is a private method). If I not do this call the `tracks` property is not set... Any ideas about this?

Thanks!